# Load KeyStore without get certificate from project files

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, x509certificate, keystore

I want to load KeyStore certificate from X509Certificate[] object but for now, I just load the certificate from Assets. I don't want to load the certificate from the file but from X509Certificate object. Any solutions?

GetCertificateChain:

```
private X509Certificate[] GetCertificateChain(string alias)
    {
        try
        {
            return KeyChain.GetCertificateChain(this, alias);
        }
        catch (KeyChainException e)
        {

        }            

        return null;
    }
```

Load certificate:

```
Stream iss = Application.Context.Assets.Open("badssl.com-cuient.p12");
hchandler.SetClientCertificate(iss, "badssl.com".ToCharArray());


 private IKeyManager[] GetKeyManagersFromClientCert(Stream pkcs12, char[] password)
    {
        if (pkcs12 != null)
        {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.GetInstance("pkcs12");
            keyStore.Load(pkcs12, password);
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.GetInstance("x509");
            kmf.Init(keyStore, password);
            return kmf.GetKeyManagers();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Could you add a little more description of what is the issue? It's unclear.

Comment: description updated